Puppet Failed to open TCP connection
I have this message on mu Debian machine :
août 29 08:37:34 puppet puppet-agent[711]: No more routes to fileserver
août 29 08:37:35 puppet puppet-agent[711]: Connection to https://puppet:8140/puppet/v3 failed, trying next route: Request to https://puppet:8140/puppet/v3 failed after 0.002 seconds: Failed to open TC
P connection to puppet:8140 (Network is unreachable - connect(2) for

xxx.x.x.x.:8140)
août 29 08:37:35 puppet puppet-agent[711]: Wrapped exception:
août 29 08:37:35 puppet puppet-agent[711]: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:8140 (Network is unreachable - connect(2) for x.x.x.x:8140)
août 29 08:37:35 puppet puppet-agent[711]: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: No more routes to puppet
août 29 08:37:35 puppet puppet-agent[711]: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
août 29 08:37:35 puppet puppet-agent[711]: Connection to https://puppet:8140/puppet/v3 failed, trying
next route: Request to https://puppet:8140/puppet/v3 failed after 0.002 seconds: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:8140 (Network is unreachable - connect(2) for xxx.x.x.x:8140)

In my puppet.conf file, I have this configuration
[main]
ssldir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl
server = puppetservername
[master]
vardir = /var/lib/puppet
cadir  = /var/lib/puppet/server/ssl/ca
dns_alt_names = puppet


What is the result of command nslookup puppet?
